# What is the key path to use in a Core Data predicate to return all subentities of a type?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

What can I add the the below predicate to fetch all subentities of a certain type? Here CfCategory is an Abstract entity with several child / subentities.

```swift
    // Fetch CfCategory from Core Data
    @FetchRequest(entity: CfCategory.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [],
                  predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == CfSubcategoryA"))
    
    private var categories: FetchedResults<CfCategory>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using

```swift
NSPredicate(“entity == %@“, MySubEntity.Entity())
```

For some reason, specifying entity name in predicate string was returning an error that entity wasn’t a keypath in the parent entity.